# Save Method not workin with the repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a method in my Service Class

```
public Optional<Product> autenticarUsuario(Optional<Product> product) {

        Optional<Product> status = repository.findById(product.get().getId());
        
        if(status.isPresent()) {
            if(product.get().getType() == 1) {
                return Optional.of(repository.save(product));
            
            } else {
                return Optional.empty();
                
            }
```

Where I need to return an ok to save if the string is "1", but return nothing if its not.
This is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    public List<Product> findAllByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
    public Optional<Product> findById(long id);
    
}
```

The error that the program gives me is:
"The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Product,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional)"

Comment: I am sorry, can you say what is lacking on my question? I already read the how to ask

Comment: I did not say( OK maybe there was a presumption) that anything was wrong, just that as a one new to stack overflow, it would be good do.  I have no idea why you received that down vote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass an argument of type Product instead of Optional. `repository.save(product.get())` also as Saad Zimat points out you should include a `product.isPresent()` check in the if statement to ensure there is an entity to save.

Comment: and add a product.isPresent() to the if statement

Comment: Good catch I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved my Service class problem but another error popped at the controller, when I try to create the put the error "The method autenticarUsuario(Optional<Product>) in the type ProductService is not applicable for the arguments (Product)" appears, 
My code is like this `@PutMapping ("/status")       
 public ResponseEntity<ProductStatus> putProductStatus(@Valid @RequestBody Product product){
 return productService.autenticarUsuario(product)
  .map(resposta -> ResponseEntity.ok(repository2.save(productStatus)))
  .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}`

Comment: The way your code is currently written, you need to pass an Optional to your service. That would be return productService.autenticarUsuario(Optional.of(product)).map(resposta -> ResponseEntity.ok(repository2.save(productStatus)))   .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()); However, you might change the service method to take a Product argument instead of Optional<Product> instead unless that violates a non-functional requirement.